# How to open a jquery popup onload instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I am trying to create a jquery popup which opens on **onload** of a page instead of **click**

presently I have a code which works on click..

**javascript.js**

```
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN

    $('[data-popup-open]').on('onload', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Open Popup #1</a>

<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <h3>hello</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

here you can see that the popup opens on click, but I want to open it on load, so how do I go about it?

Sorry, but I found the answer...

**EDITED javascript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-popup="popup-1"]').fadeIn(350);
});
```

Comment: Please either answer your own question, or delete this question.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't put solved in the title and don't put an answer in the question. Post an answer and accept it instead.

Answer (score 0):

So, i dont know if you have multiple popups in your page but i built a solution thinks in many. (easy to port to one)

```
$(function() {
        var popupTriggers = $('[data-popup-open]');

    popupTriggers.on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').toggle(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    popupTriggers.each(function(){
        var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arthurvasconcelos/dfkmjb7k/)